# How to check elasticsearch query performance?

Tags: elasticsearch, sense

I need to check elasticsearch query performance. But due to caching I am unable to figure out actual query performance. Is there any way to stop caching.

I had tried `_cache/clear` as per suggested below document.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-clearcache.html

```
$ curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_cache/clear'
```

Also tried , set `index.cache.filter.type` to `none` in `elasticsearch.yml`

```
index.cache.filter.type : none
```

I using `Sense` to run `elasticseaech query`.

Any other way to doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe restart your elastic search cluster, then run some queries that hit more or less the same data but not the actual query you want to test, and then the query you want to test.

I also notice the first query you run against a restarted cluster is slow, but after that everything tends to be fast.

It's very possible that ElasticSearch isn't even caching the query you're trying to get performance data on, it's just really really fast ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable caching in index settings:

```
PUT /<index name>/_settings
{
  "index.requests.cache.enable": false
}
```